# Netty Game Client Hangs

Tags: java, swing, netty

I have a game client that I made using swing. When Netty connects the client will not update or render anymore. Is there a way to have netty run in the background? Should I have netty in another thread? I am trying to get the client to render and update while netty is reading and writing in the background.

Comment: Yes, you will need to use Netty in another thread.

Comment: Read about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: Ok. Also how do I write data from outside that thread. Like sending the players position to the server?

Comment: *"Ok. Also how do I.."*  SO is a Q&A site, not a help desk.  Getting references to objects so you can write to them should be asked on a separate Q&A.

Comment: *"Should I have netty in another thread?"* - Yes, remember though, Swing is not thread safe

Comment: Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic before asking a question